# how to refer to UILabel in NSMutableArray in Obj-C

Tags: objective-c, arrays, label

i've got some code:

```
    int k = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 9; j++) {
            label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(30*i, 30*j, 30, 30)];
            [label setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", filterTab[i][j]]];
            [label setTextAlignment:UITextAlignmentCenter];
            [label setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:15]];
            [label setTextColor:[UIColor grayColor]];
            [label setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
            [label setTag:k];
            [array addObject:label];
            [tableFilter addSubview:label];
            k++;
        }
    }
```

so, this create 81 labels and add all to view and to array and i've got button: DO SOMETHING and this button have action. this action must change text in selected label with tag = 80.

how can i do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can pull the `UILabel` view directly from the `tableFilter` view without using the array you've created as,

```
UILabel *label = (UILabel *)[tableFilter viewWithTag:80];
label.text = @"Foo";
```